# UIPanGestureRecognizer manually start gesture

Tags: objective-c, uipangesturerecognizer, touchesbegan

I have a bunch of views setup on the screen and by using touchesBegan: and touchesMoved: overrides in my main view, I let the user drag around the screen and track the position. When a user hovers over one of the views, I want that view to start a pan gesture recognizer from it's center.

From testing I've seen that when a pan gesture is active, the touchesBegan: and touchesMoved: methods don't get called, which is perfect for my case where I want them to drag over to the view and then that view handles the gesture.

Everything works fine except I can't seem to find a way to start the pan gesture when the user hovers over the view. Even if I call touchesBegan: on that view it doesn't get fooled into thinking the user just tapped and it should start the gesture recognizer.

Do you guys know any way of manually triggering the start of a pan gesture recognizer?
By start I mean manually making the pan gesture think the user just tapped and for the pan gesture to start tracking the touches and movement